# How to install RSS reader NewsFlash (successor to FeedReader)?

Tags: software-installation, rss

RSS reader NewsFlash (successor to FeedReader) is a program designed to complement an already existing web-based RSS reader account (Support for **Miniflux, Feedly, Fever, NewsBlur, Feedbin, local RSS feeds**). It combines all the advantages of web based services like syncing across all your devices with everything you expect from a modern desktop program: Desktop notifications, fast search and filtering, tagging, handy keyboard shortcuts and having access to all your articles as long as you like (more info [on their Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/news-flash/news_flash_gtk)).
How can it be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have **flatpack and Flathub repository support** on your Ubuntu system, otherwise install it according to the [quick setup guide](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/).
Then you can **install the flatpak** from:

1. The pre-installed Ubuntu/GNOME Software App
2. From [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.gitlab.newsflash) ([according to News Flash Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/news-flash/news_flash_gtk))
3. A terminal with the command: `flatpak install flathub com.gitlab.newsflash`
4. Now you should be able to start it from your launcher or from a terminal: `flatpak run com.gitlab.newsflash`

**Newsflash supports** Miniflux, local RSS, fever, NewsBlur, Inoreader, feedbin.

**[Newsblur](https://newsblur.com/) usage**: Use URL https://www.newsblur.com/ [for login](https://gitlab.com/news-flash/news_flash_gtk/-/issues/284).

**Feedly**: Until further notice [**Feedly support is discontinued because of API secret expiration**, for details see bug report on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/news-flash/news_flash/-/issues/66).

**If you trouble to scrape a page:**
If you want a specific site to work well with the scraper you should look into "full text feed" config files:
https://github.com/fivefilters/ftr-site-config#how-to-write-a-site-config-file
They are small text files containing xpath rules how to extract article content from a single specific site. Since you can fine tune them they usually work best. Only difficulties are sites which are badly structured and make it hard to define which elements contain the content and when the site updates its layout / design.
These files can be dropped into `~/.var/app/com.gitlab.newsflash/data/news-flash/scraper_data/`.
Restart the app to read the new config files.
Source: [Gitlab bug report](https://gitlab.com/news-flash/news_flash_gtk/-/issues/146).

[image]